# running a python program in the command line without "./"

Tags: python, linux, command-line, command

Let's say I have a program called "hello". It is a python script and I want to run it at the linux command line.

I've been able to remove the .py extension as well as the interpreter.

Now when I run it it is [user..path] $ ./hello

it works, but how do I remove the "./". I've already applied the chmod a+x argument to the file and a shebang line at the front of my script.

Basically, I am asking how to run the script as $ hello

Answer (score 2):

Add `.` to the end of your `$PATH` variable.

```
PATH=$PATH:.
```

Then it will search the current directory when looking for programs to run.

Note that you should *not* generally put `.` at the beginning of `$PATH`. If you `cd` into someone else's directory, and they have a program that's the same name as a system program (e.g. `ls`), you'll execute their version instead of the real one.

You could also create your own directory where you install programs, and put that directory in `$PATH`.

```
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

Now you copy `hello` to your `~/bin` directory and run `hello`.